# Sort through .txt file using tab / no tab structure

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, text, foreach

I have a .txt file with the following contents

```
header 1
    sub header 1
    sub header 2 
header 2
    sub header 3
    sub header 4
```

The sub headers are tabbed.

I have the current code, but I cannot deliminite the .txt file /t for some reason:

```
$str = file_get_contents($_FILES["text_file"]["tmp_name"]);
$lines = explode("\n", $str);

$i= 0;

foreach($lines as $key => $value){

    if(strpos($value, '/t') !== false){ 
        echo 'tab'; 
    }else{ 
        echo 'no tab'; 
    } 

    $i++;
}
```

What script can I use to sort this structure into the following type of array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        "name" => "header 1"
        "subheadings" => Array("sub header 1","sub header 2")
        )
    [1] => Array (
        "name" => "header 2"
        "subheadings" => Array("sub header 3","sub header 4")
        )
    )
```

Thanks

Chris

Comment: try to use `"\t"` because a string with `'` will just take it literally as `\t`, and it's `\t` instead of `/t`. Proof: http://3v4l.org/eBP3f

Comment: Nice one :) Gives me a good starting point haha

Answer (score 0):

In fact you should also not use `!==false` comparison and use "\t" as **EaterOfCode** mentioned in comment.

In foreach loop you should rather use:

```
foreach($lines as $key => $value){

    if(strpos($value, "\t") === 0){
        echo 'tab';
    }else{
        echo 'no tab';
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Earlier if you used `!==false` if tab was at the end of line or in the middle it would be also considered as `!==false` and you should rather check if tab is at the beginning of the string and not at any position of the string

Comment: '=== 0' messes up my array structure. weird :\

Answer (score 0):

Using the useful comment above i've come up with this basic solution. This seems to work as i've got the array as I asked in the original question. Thanks.

```
foreach($lines as $key => $value){

    if(strpos($value, "\t") === false){
        $o[$h]['name'] = $value; 

        $h++;
    }
    else{ 
        if(is_array($o)){
            $o[$h-1]['subheadings'][] = trim($value);
        }
        else{
            echo 'error';
        }

        $s++;
    } 

    $a++;
}
```

Comment: To be more precise (and a bit faster), you can use `$value[0] === "\t"` because now if a header uses an `\t` it will bug out

Comment: so `if(strpos($value[0], "\t") === false)` ?

Comment: you can access a string as array, and it will return the character on that place (Warning: totally not unicode safe.) as you can see here: http://3v4l.org/0ICAv and strpos just goes through the whole string till it finds the needle which can be time consuming. so just `if($value[0] === "\t"){`. (assuming your lines really start with `\t`. if not, you may want to check for wild `\r`'s at the beginning of $value).